# Android: Why does my EditText keep its value, even on orientation change?

Tags: android, orientation, android-edittext

this is a question out of curiosity.

I recently just learned that i have to care about keeping my activity state on orientation changes myself.

But in one of my Layouts, the Edittext just keeps its value and i do not get why?
Obviously i would like to reproduce this behaviour for other EditTexts...

Heres the Layout, the edittext is android:id="@+id/createlistactivity_listname_edittext"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter a Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/createlistactivity_listname_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="Name..."
        android:singleLine="true" >

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CreateListActivity_HeaderLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add Products to your new List"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="No Products available. Insert some Products in the Products menu  first" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/CreateListActivity_BottomBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CreateListActivity_SaveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="saveButtonClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/tick_32" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CreateListActivity_CancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="cancelButtonClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/block_32_2" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the onCreate for the activity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.createlistactivity_layout);

    _selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    _productDAO = new ProductDAO(getApplication());
    _listDAO = new ListDAO(getApplication());
    _productCursor = _productDAO.getAllProductsCursor();

    startManagingCursor(_productCursor);

    setUpListView();    

    final EditText listNameEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.createlistactivity_listname_edittext);

    listNameEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(listNameEditText
                        .getApplicationWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });     
}
```

this is the code of another activity which contains edittexts that do not preserve their state

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/productImage"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/productview_toprow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/productview_productname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Product Name"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/productview_pricelabel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/productview_price_edittext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="0.0"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/productview_unitlabel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/productview_unit_edittext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="kg|ml|..." />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and the onCreate...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.productview);

    _productName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.productview_productname);
    _productPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.productview_price_edittext);
    _productUnit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.productview_unit_edittext);
    _productImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.productImage);

    _productDAO = new ProductDAO(getApplication()); 

    //set data from database
    _product = _productDAO.getProduct(getIntent().getExtras().getString(DataBaseKeys.PRODUCT_NAME));

    if(_product != null)
    {
        _productName.setText(_product.getName());
        _productImage.setImageBitmap(_product.getIcon());
        _productPrice.setText(""+_product.getPrice());
        _productUnit.setText(_product.getUnit());
        _productIcon = _product.getIcon();
    }           

}
```

Comment: You mean that the other EditTexts in the other layouts do not maintain their value? Can you add some code from their Activities?

Comment: Yes. They dont. I will edit code of another activity into the question

Answer (score 4):

Well the `View`s in android do keep some of its state. Like `EditText` keep its text so you dont have to save it `onSaveInstanceState`. Other examples are `ListView` keep the scroll position. `EditText` also keeps scroll position if it multi-line text.

But some of the thing a user has to takecare like if you are having a Note App, you have to store Note ID which is being edited so that on orientation change you know what you are working on.

This is a standard way of Android, nothing unusual here. For more details refer.

[Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState)

Regarding one of your activity not behaving as aspected is because of code:

```
 _product = _productDAO.getProduct(getIntent().getExtras().getString(DataBaseKeys.PRODUCT_NAME));

if(_product != null)
{
    _productName.setText(_product.getName());
    _productImage.setImageBitmap(_product.getIcon());
    _productPrice.setText(""+_product.getPrice());
    _productUnit.setText(_product.getUnit());
    _productIcon = _product.getIcon();
}
```

You are overriding the values of the edit text. Try this log statement before `if` statement.

```
Log.i("EDIT_NOT_WORKING", "VALUE OF EDIT: " + _productName.getText());
```

You should see that it will print the entered value.

Comment: well the point is that other EditText elements do not save the input. and i dont see any difference that could cause this behaviour

Comment: So you are saying, you have `EditText a` with value say `"Hello"` and when orientation changed it is empty again?

Comment: I have an Activity A with a Layout A, containing an EditText. If you enter "Hello" and change the orientation it keeps the "Hello". I have another Activity B with a Layout B, containing an EditText. If you enter "Hello" and change the orientation, the "Hello" is gone.. Both are posted in the Question

Comment: Hello havexz, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatley its not correct. the log statement prints an empty string. i am only populating the edittext if the product is in the database, which is working fine. only if the user creates a new entry the error occurs (the if statement will not be executed)

Comment: Can you try commenting that `if` block and try again. To me it looks like you are saving the empty product in `onPause`. `onPause` is called during orientation change.

Comment: Hi havexz, thanks for your help. after trying your suggestions i got frustrated and deleted the autogenerated R file a few times... its repopulating the edittexts fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give an id to your editText, it won't save the value on screen change. You have to give an id so that the value is saved, even if the screen changes orientation.